# EF Core Adding Duplicate Entities To Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build my controller to check whether an entity (StockData) already exists in the database and, if not, add it. Otherwise, it should not be added. However, the code I built is adding it always and I don't understand why.

I am trying to build an app (ASP.NET Core MVC, using SQL Server and EF Core) that loads stock data from an API and displays it on the page. While that works, I want to avoid saving duplicate entities of StockData, as otherwise my database will continuously fill with already existing data on every call.

Here is my controller and my Product and StockData classes:

```
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

        public StockController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var symbol = "MSFT";
            var name = "Microsoft";
            Product product;

            if(dbContext.Products.Any(p => p.Symbol == symbol))
            {
                product = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Symbol == symbol);
            }
            else
            {
                product = new Product
                {
                    Symbol = symbol,
                    Name = name
                };
                dbContext.Add(product);
            }

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var apiResponse = $"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={symbol}&interval=5min&apikey=APIKEY&datatype=csv".GetStringFromUrl();
            var stocks = apiResponse.FromCsv<List<StockData>>().ToList();

            product.Data = stocks;

            foreach (var stock in product.Data)
            {
                if(!dbContext.StockData.Any(s => s.Timestamp.Equals(stock.Timestamp) && s.ProductId.Equals(product.ProductId)))
                {
                    dbContext.Add(stock);
                }
            }

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return View(product);
        }
    }



public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<StockData> Data { get; set; }
    }

public class StockData
    {
        [Ignore]
        public int StockDataId { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public int ModelId { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Open { get; set; }
        public string High { get; set; }
        public string Low { get; set; }
        public string Close { get; set; }
        public string Volume { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are duplicate Stocks or Products being saved? What do you consider a duplicate?

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the timestamp.  if(!dbContext.StockData.Any(s => s.Timestamp.Equals(stock.Timestamp) && s.ProductId.Equals(product.ProductId)))

Comment: Duplicate Stocks, Products aren't saved again if they already exist in the database (my bad, will try to make it clear in the OP)

Comment: Are you adding and updating stocks? or just updating?

Comment: Well, the API extracts new stock data when there is some, so on every call, I am getting a mix between the new stock data (the most recent ones) and the older ones. I only want to add the new ones, that don't exist in the database yet, while avoiding adding the "old" data since it already exists in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found out what caused the issue of duplication.

The `foreach` method was actually working fine with prohibiting to add new stocks to the database according to the `if` statement's conditions.

But, for some reason, the `product.Data = stocks;` was somehow *automatically* adding that `product.Data`, that is, the newly fetched `stocks` collection from the API, to the database, even without any explicit methods to do so.

I am not sure why this is happening, but I refactored my code to use a temporary stock list (`tempStocks`)instead in order to avoid adding the whole fetched `stocks` collection to the `product.Data`, like this:

```
var apiResponse = $"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={symbol}&interval=1min&apikey=APIKEY&datatype=csv&outputsize=full".GetStringFromUrl();
var tempStocks = apiResponse.FromCsv<List<StockData>>().ToList();
var newStocks = new List<StockData>();

foreach (var stock in tempStocks)
{
     if (!dbContext.StockData.Any(s => s.Timestamp == stock.Timestamp && s.ProductId == product.ProductId))
     {
          newStocks.Add(stock);
     }
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

product.Data = newStocks;
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but I hope it helps someone who hits the same issue.

Comment: I would be careful of putting a call to the database inside of a foreach statement.

Comment: Are you referring to the check whether a stock exists in the database or the SaveChanges method?

Answer (score 1):

This should update the record if it finds an Id, else it should add it.

```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public StockController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var symbol = "MSFT";
        var name = "Microsoft";
        Product product;

        product = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Symbol.Equals(symbol));


        if (product == null)
        {
            dbContext.Add(new Product() { Symbol = symbol, Name = name });
        }
        else
        {
            dbContext.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        dbContext.SaveChanges();


        var apiResponse = $"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={symbol}&interval=5min&apikey=APIKEY&datatype=csv".GetStringFromUrl();
        var stocks = apiResponse.FromCsv<List<StockData>>().ToList();

        product.Data = stocks;

        foreach (var stock in product.Data)
        {
            var newStock = dbContext.StockData.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ProductId.Equals(product.ProductId));
            if (!dbContext.StockData.Any(s => s.Timestamp.Equals(stock.Timestamp)))
            {
                if (newStock == null)
                {
                    dbContext.Add(stock);
                }
                else
                {
                    dbContext.Entry(stock).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's sadly not working. I am getting the following error:

InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>+Enumerator.MoveNextRare()

App.Controllers.StockController.Index() in StockController.cs
(on line) foreach (var stock in product.Data)

Comment: On what line? Please provide complete stack trace.